# Show that a permutation equation has 5 solutions

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, permutation-cycles

How can I show that this permutation equation has 5 solutions:

$\pi^{2013}$ = (1 9) (2 8) (3 7) (4 6) (5)

Since the cycle structure is [2, 2, 2, 2, 1] then the only possible cyclic structure for the solution $\pi$ is the same one since gcd(2, 2013) = 1 and all other multiples of 2 would yield the same result. Now 2013 mod 2 = 1 so $\pi^1$. Isn't that the only solution?

Comment: It depends where $\pi$ lives. $\pi$ can have arbitrarily many $3$-cycles.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\ a,b,c,d,e,f\ $ are distinct, then
$$
\pmatrix{a& b&c&d &e &f}^3=\pmatrix{a&d}\pmatrix{b &e}\pmatrix{c&f}\ ,
$$
and $\ 2013=3\times671\ .$ Therefore
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{a& b&c&d &e &f}^{2013}&=\pmatrix{a& b&c&d &e &f}^{3\times671}\\
&=\big(\pmatrix{a&d}\pmatrix{b &e}\pmatrix{c&f}\big)^{671}\\
&=\pmatrix{a&d}\pmatrix{b &e}\pmatrix{c&f}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: (ab)^(2013) mod 3 would be 1, therefor (ab) would stay (ab)? What do you mean by 2013 = 3 * 617

Comment: Apologies for the typo., which I've now fixed.  I've also expanded the hint a little.